# Select at least one checkbox validation

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, mean.io

I have the array of checkboxes from which I want to select at least one checkbox and want to display the validation error

How can I do that? Here is my code

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : submitted && form.field.$invalid }">
    <div class="col-md-12"><label for="field" >Select at leat one</label></div>
        <div class="col-md-2" data-ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4]">
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="field[$index]" value="{{i}}" data-ng-model="form.field[$index]" required/>Choice {{i+1}}</label>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="submitted && form.field.$invalid" class="help-block">
          <p ng-show="form.field.$error.required">Please select at least one choice<p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wasn't really sure about your requirements so I plunkered a bit and used both filter and some functions to validate a minimum of one checked checkbox. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hSxUhTjiHlSCv5IFcehf?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @skubski Please post as answer with some description so I can accept your answer.

Comment: Added it, thanks. @Dau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use native javascript functions to iterate over your array. First that come in mind are [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

With **some**, you can determine if one item in your array validates true and with **filter** you can find all the elements that pass a custom expression and check if the newly created array has a certain length.

E.g.:

```
var atleastOne = this.form.field.some(function(element) {
    return element;
 });

 if(atleastOne) {
   window.alert("validated with some");
 } 

 var filtered = this.form.field.filter(function(element) {
    if(element) { return element; }
 });

 if(filtered.length > 0) {
    window.alert('validated with filter');
 }
```

You can flag the variables that show the errors based on the results of your validation. A working demo can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hSxUhTjiHlSCv5IFcehf?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

You can create your checkbox list object array properly then bind it. Please find the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shivajibarge86/4Lmj0gjz/5/)

```
<div ng-controller="ChckbxsCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="chk in items">
    <div style="width:500px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000;">
         <B>{{chk.group}}</B><br>
    <label ng-repeat="vale in chk.values">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vale.val" />
    {{vale.label}}</label>
         </div>
     <span ng-show="chk.isValid">Select at least one option from {{chk.group}}</span>
        </br> </div>
</br>
```